# Magento 2 - How to add wysiwyg editor in frontend PHTML file?

Tags: magento2, frontend, wysiwyg

I have one inquiry form on frontend custom module. 
I wanted to use `wysiwyg editor` in frontend PHTML file. 
I have read many thread on community which have tutorials for adding wysiwyg in backend form. 
I am finding way for displaying them in frontend form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have a textarea:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="input-text"></textarea>
```

then to add wysiwyg editor to the textarea, you just need to write following code in Javascript file or tag:

```
 require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
    ], function(jQuery){

    var config = {}, 
        editor;

    jQuery.extend(config, {
        settings: {
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : 'bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,' +
                                        'fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code',
            theme_advanced_buttons2: null,
            theme_advanced_buttons3: null,
            theme_advanced_buttons4: null
        }
    });
    editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup(
        'comment',
        config
    );
    editor.turnOn();
    jQuery('#comment')
        .addClass('wysiwyg-editor')
        .data(
            'wysiwygEditor',
            editor
        );
});
```

Comment: @dsmagento, have you tried above solution?

Comment: @dsmagento, did the solution work for you?

Comment: Yes thanks I got it but i am not able to write anything in it. :(

Comment: I think there may be some other reason like JS conflict, ID mismatch etc. because it is working fine here. Please check http://nimb.ws/zFTScA

Comment: actually at first load cursor is not blinking in side if i press any button like bold, or for alignment then cursor appears.

Comment: how can we add javascript code?means can i write js code in .phtml or any web/js files? please send me the path where we are the js code?

Comment: @RamSampathi, as mentioned in the question, you need to write this javascript code in the PHTML file or you can include a custom JS file and write the code in it.

Comment: wrote in .phtml like http://prntscr.com/mkzk63 .but its not working.any wrong in this

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: version -- magento2.3.0

Comment: I have just rechecked the code in Magento version 2.2.7 and found it working. Please check https://nimb.ws/ixfG4E for reference.

Comment: In Magento 2.3.0, I think there is some change in the tinyMCE library. Please check the changelog of this version.

Comment: i see an error like in log file "invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89719/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-arora-and-ram-sampathi).

Comment: not working in magento2.4

Comment: @Himanshu, it will not work in Magento 2.4. The library has been changed after 2.3 version.

Answer (score 5):

If your Magento version is 2.3.x then use the following code to add wysiwyg editor in frontend PHTML file.

Add Textarea:

```
<textarea name="post_content" class="input-text" id="post_content"></textarea>
```

Now replace textarea with wysiwyg editor by adding following code at bottom of your PHTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
], function(jQuery){
    wysiwyg = new wysiwygSetup('post_content', {
        'width':'100%',  // defined width of editor
        'height':'300px', // height of editor
        'plugins':[{'name':'image'}], // for image
        'tinymce4':{'toolbar':'formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap','plugins':'advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table'
        }
    });
    wysiwyg.setup('exact');
});
</script>
```

Comment: not working on 2.3.5 and 2.4 ver. can you help

Comment: Thanks but data not load in  wysiwyg

Answer (score 0):

The code above from Sagar is good. For those who can't get it to work, there might be a typo in the example.

**new wysiwygSetup** expects a field id, not a field name.
So if you pass **post_content** to the editor constructor and **post_content** is an element id, it should work.

Just make sure you add **id="post_content"** to the textarea HTML tag.